# How to bind socket to IP with java?

Tags: java, linux, sockets

I have a JAVA application which runs on Linux. I open a socket that binds to all IP. In production this is not acceptable.

```
$ netstat -ano | grep 104
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:104                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

I which to do this:

```
$ netstat -ano | grep 104
tcp        0      viewer1.com:104                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Is this something I can change in my Linux box (red hat) or is it application specific. i.e. I have to modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you'll need to modify the Java application to specify a bind address.

[The most commonly used API for server socket construction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29) binds to all address by default. However, [there is another](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress%29) that can bind to a specific address. There's a small chance that the application is already using the latter constructor, and it's just not configured with a value. If that's the case, you just need to find out how to configure an address.